# What's the difference between "Veto" and "Hard Block"?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, firewall, wfp

Is the following code called "Veto", "Hard Block", or both?

```
if (FWP_ACTION_PERMIT == classifyOut->actionType 
 && FlagOn(classifyOut->rights, FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE))
{
    classifyOut->rights = 0;
    classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
}
```

The documentation about this issue is vague.

Please visit: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364008(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It is a soft block since ACTION_WRITE is turned on.

Comment: No. I set the rights to 0, and return FWP_ACTION_BLOCK, so it is certainly a "Hard Block", but I don't know if this is also a "Veto".

Answer (score 1):

It is a **Hard Block**, but not a **Veto**.

A hard action is an action where you reset the *FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE* flag in addition to setting the *actionType* to *FWP_ACTION_BLOCK* or *FWP_ACTION_PERMIT*. (This is not explicitly defined in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FWP/filter-arbitration), but it can be inferred from the first table.)

In your code, you're resetting the flag, then setting *actionType* to *FWP_ACTION_BLOCK*, making your action a **Hard Block**:

```
classifyOut->rights = 0;
classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
```

As explained in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FWP/filter-arbitration),

> A Veto is a Block action returned by the filter when the FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE flag was reset prior to calling the filter.

In your code, you're only issuing a block if the flag is set, making your action **not a Veto**:

```
if ( ... && FlagOn(classifyOut->rights, FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE) {...}
```